# how to load files on hadoop cluster using apache pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script, and need to load files from local hadoop cluster. I can list the files using hadoop command: hadoop fs –ls /repo/mydata,` 
but when i tried to load files in pig script, it failed. the load statement is like this:

```
in = LOAD '/repo/mydata/2012/02' USING PigStorage() AS (event:chararray, user:chararray)
```

the error message is:

```
Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/repo/mydata/2012/02
```

any idea? thanks

Comment: got it, should be like this: in = LOAD "hdfs:/repo/mydata/2012/02" USING PigStorage() AS ...

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion:

1. Create a folder in hdfs : `hadoop fs -mkdir /pigdata`
2. Load the file to the created hdfs folder: `hadoop fs -put /opt/pig/tutorial/data/excite-small.log /pigdata`

(or you can do it from grunt shell as `grunt> copyFromLocal /opt/pig/tutorial/data/excite-small.log /pigdata`)

1. Execute the pig latin script :

   ```
      grunt> set debug on

      grunt> set job.name 'first-p2-job'

      grunt> log = LOAD 'hdfs://hostname:54310/pigdata/excite-small.log' AS 
                 (user:chararray, time:long, query:chararray); 
      grunt> grpd = GROUP log BY user; 
      grunt> cntd = FOREACH grpd GENERATE group, COUNT(log); 
      grunt> STORE cntd INTO 'output';
   ```
2. The output file will be stored in `hdfs://hostname:54310/pigdata/output`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.. please find my suggestions below:

1. To start working on PIG please type:
     **[root@localhost training]# pig -x local**
2. Now type load statement as I am doing in below example:
    **grunt> a= LOAD '/home/training/pig/TempFile.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (c1:chararray,c2:chararray,c3:chararray);**

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the space on the either side of "="
in=LOAD '/repo/mydata/2012/02' USING PigStorage() AS (event:chararray, user:chararray)